# kernel extension is not always loaded at boot time on OSX

Tags: macos, usb, iokit, kernel-extension

I do have a kernel extension for USB-Devices using IOKitPersonalities. Replugging one of the devices the kext will always be loaded as expected but for devices already connected at startup this sometimes fails. In this case the device itself is recognized by the system and can be found at SystemInformation/USB. The Icon is the standard yellow one from apple instead of the green one provided by our kext.
One interesting fact:
When I have two devices connected, one directly at the mac pro the other at the keyboard-hub, it might occur that only the one at the hub triggers a kext load. This one is always about 2 seconds later in the syslog as the other one:

```
27.04.16 10:17:58,000 kernel[0]: USBMSC Identifier (non-unique): 000003448813 0x64f 0x3e9 0x100, 1  
...  
27.04.16 10:17:59,000 kernel[0]: USBMSC Identifier (non-unique): 000000506497 0x64f 0x3e9 0x100, 1  
...  
27.04.16 10:18:01,000 kernel[0]: XXXXXXX KEXT.5G/K64 (Version: 5.20.078 - G) loaded.
```

If all devices are successfully recognized the "Kext loaded line" will be found short after each device.

Some facts about the kext:
- it is installed to /Library/Extensions (System/Library/Extensions for pre Mavericks). According to http://asciiwwdc.com/2013/sessions/707 the place to be.
- it is signed (verified in SystemInformation/Software/Extensions)
- installation requires a restart
- touch /System/Library/Extensions and
- touch /Library/Extensions is called at the end of the installation
- after the installation the kernel cache seems to be updated

I first thought the system might not rebuild the prelinked kernel when the restart comes early, but found this at syslog:

```
28.04.16 17:02:28,000 kernel[0]: Resetting IOCatalogue.  
28.04.16 17:02:29,253 com.apple.kextd[47]: '/' updating, delaying reboot.  
28.04.16 17:02:29,254 com.apple.kextcache[874]: rebuilding //System/Library/PrelinkedKernels/prelinkedkernel  
28.04.16 17:02:29,257 com.apple.kextcache[878]: / locked; waiting for lock.  
28.04.16 17:02:30,424 com.apple.kextcache[879]: kext file:///System/Library/Extensions/JMicronATA.kext/ is in hash exception list, allowing to load  
28.04.16 17:02:34,645 com.apple.kextcache[880]: / locked; waiting for lock.  
28.04.16 17:02:52,470 com.apple.kextcache[879]: Created old kernelcache copy "/System/Library/Caches/com.apple.kext.caches/Startup/kernelcache"  
28.04.16 17:02:52,470 com.apple.kextcache[879]: Created prelinked kernel "/System/Library/PrelinkedKernels/prelinkedkernel"  
28.04.16 17:02:52,470 com.apple.kextcache[879]: Created prelinked kernel using "/System/Library/Kernels/kernel"  
28.04.16 17:02:52,490 com.apple.kextcache[874]: /System/Library/PrelinkedKernels/prelinkedkernel not cached.  
28.04.16 17:02:52,000 kernel[0]: hfs: mounted Recovery HD on device disk0s3  
28.04.16 17:02:52,513 mds[62]: (Volume.Normal:2464) volume:0x7fd77c06be00 ********** Bootstrapped Creating a default store:0 SpotLoc:(null) SpotVerLoc:(null) occlude:0 /Volumes/Recovery HD  
28.04.16 17:02:52,565 fseventsd[48]: Logging disabled completely for device:1: /Volumes/Recovery HD  
28.04.16 17:02:53,100 com.apple.kextcache[874]: Successfully updated disk0s3.  
28.04.16 17:02:53,000 kernel[0]: hfs: unmount initiated on Recovery HD on device disk0s3  
28.04.16 17:02:53,154 com.apple.kextd[47]: / is still busy, delaying reboot.  
28.04.16 17:02:53,154 com.apple.kextcache[878]: Lock acquired; proceeding.  
28.04.16 17:02:53,157 com.apple.kextcache[878]: /: helper partitions appear up to date.  
28.04.16 17:02:53,157 com.apple.kextd[47]: / is still busy, delaying reboot.  
28.04.16 17:02:53,157 com.apple.kextcache[880]: Lock acquired; proceeding.  
28.04.16 17:02:53,159 com.apple.kextcache[880]: /: helper partitions appear up to date.  
28.04.16 17:02:53,160 com.apple.kextd[47]:  up to date; unblocking reboot.  
28.04.16 17:02:53,160 shutdown[871]: reboot by ls:   
28.04.16 17:02:53,000 kernel[0]: Kext loading now disabled.  
28.04.16 17:02:53,000 kernel[0]: Kext unloading now disabled.  
28.04.16 17:02:53,000 kernel[0]: Kext autounloading now disabled.  
28.04.16 17:02:53,000 kernel[0]: Kernel requests now disabled.  
28.04.16 17:03:02,000 bootlog[0]: BOOT_TIME 1461855782 0
```

when and where:
- I do have this issue on 10.11.4 but did see it also on 10.10
- My impression is, that if it works directly after the installation, it never fails. So I think the problem might be about the kext missing in some "loading at boot time list" sometimes.

I hope someone has an idea where I might proceed my research.

Comment: Ask on https://apple.stackexchange.com

Comment: @trojanfoe apple.stackexchange.com is for sysadmin/user level questions; this is clearly a question only relevant to kext development, and is therefore on-topic here. (especially in the kext and iokit tags)

Comment: @pmdj I didn't get the impression that the OP was developing this kernel extension, only that they "had it".  If that's true then it's not on-topic.

Comment: It's about kext development although I'd appreciate it not having to change the kext itself.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say it explicitly, but from the comment about the icon, I take it this is a USB mass storage device?

OS X can boot from USB drives, so the standard USB mass storage driver must be in the kext cache/prelinked kernel. I suspect you haven't configured your kext to be included in this, so if the system detects your device before the root file system is mounted and /Library/Extensions is scanned, it will end up using the standard driver instead.

The solution is [the `OSBundleRequired` property](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/KEXTConcept/Articles/infoplist_keys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009481-SW2) in your kext's Info.plist file. If you set this to `Local-Root`, it tells the system that it can boot/root from your device/kext, and that it should be included in the local kext cache.

The kext cache is rebuilt whenever you modify or `touch` the `/Library/Extensions` or `/System/Library/Extensions` directory; it doesn't matter if it actually needs rebuilding, or if the added kext is included in the cache: it will always rebuild it when this happens. The `OSBundleRequired` property is what controls which kexts are included.

Comment: `OSBundleRequired` is already set to `Local-Root`. I observed that sometimes there are old entries lingering in `/System/Library/Caches/com.apple.kext.caches/Startup/loadedkextmt.plist`. After uninstalling the kext it is still in this list. Do you have any Idea when loadedkextmt.plist is updated?